# Can flutter pictures have the same file name?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Can't flutter pictures have the same file name?
Is it not allowed to have the same file name in different folders?
[image]

Comment: Also add pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Of course, I added in pubspec.yaml. '- assets/' and '- assets/icon/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter is a Global Framework that runs the only main.dart and pubsc.yaml file is getting image based on image name from assets folder so if you have files with the same name in the assets folder no matters that are in a different folder, that shows last execute code line image.

Answer (score 0):

Just try renaming that asset name and check.
You can find out where the problem occurs.